# APC cache not working

Tags: apc

Recently switched to a VPS and after a seamless transition I realised my APC opCode cache is no longer working, I get the message:

No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.

Tried to upload a new PHP script with latest version but no change. Will I have to run a fresh install or there a possibility a setting on my server is causing this to no longer work? As its a VPS my hosting company will charge to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your [runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php) for the value of [apc.enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enabled). If the cache is enabled, it should be:

`apc.enabled = 1`

You can use
    `phpinfo();`
to check for this variable, or execute
    `ini_get('apc.enabled');`

If it's not set to 1, you must [set](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) it in your `php.ini` file, or your apache `httpd.conf`.